# Using a Fortran90 subroutine with arguments in c++

Tags: c++, function, scope, fortran

I'm trying to use some fortran 90 subroutines in a c++ program. I have a function `writio` without any arguments that works fine, but my function `twice` doesn't do what it should. This is my first fortran function so the problem is probably somewhere in the file `rocker.f90`:

```
MODULE rocker

    CONTAINS

    SUBROUTINE writio
        WRITE(*,*) "writings"
    END SUBROUTINE writio

    SUBROUTINE twice(number, double)
        REAL*8, INTENT(IN) :: number
        REAL*8, INTENT(OUT) :: double
        WRITE(*,*) 2.0*number
        double=2.0*number;
    END SUBROUTINE twice

END MODULE rocker
```

This one I compile using `f95 -c rocker.f90`. Then I want to use the subroutines in the c++ program `testcf.cpp`:

```
using namespace std;
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <iostream>    
#include <iomanip>  
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

extern "C" {
    extern void __rocker_MOD_writio();
    extern void __rocker_MOD_twice(double d1, double d2);
}

int main()  {

    __rocker_MOD_writio();
    double d1=3.5, d2;
    __rocker_MOD_twice(d1, d2);
    cout << d1 << "   " << d2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I compile this using `g++ testcf.cpp rocker.o -lgfortran -o testcf`, and when running I get the following output:

```
 writings
  -3.59651870E+36
```

and then the program freezes. So it seems maybe the variable hasn't been passed correctly from c++ to f90?

EDIT: It seems the problem is not (only) in the Fortran code, because I can run it from the fortran program  `runrocker.f90`:

```
PROGRAM runrocker
    USE rocker, ONLY: writio, twice
    IMPLICIT NONE 

    REAL*8 :: d1=3.5, d2=0.0    

    CALL writio()
    CALL twice(d1, d2)
    WRITE(*,*) d1, "  ", d2


END PROGRAM runrocker
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your second parameter to `twice` is `OUT`, you probably want a reference:

```
 extern void __rocker_MOD_twice(double d1, double& d2);
```

Comment: Thanks! I just noticed that in the tutorial I was using too, should read more closely.